# Did Andrew Grayson resign, or not?

Tags: frontlines

In *Fields of Fire*, Andrew Grayson comments that

> I have a promise to keep to the Lazarus Brigades, to train their
> troops for a year and a half, and I'll have to resign my commission to
> keep that promise.

But in the following book, *Points of Impact*, he states

> I fulfilled a promise after Mars and joined the Lazarus Brigades as a
> Fleet adviser, training troops and getting mixed up in PRC conflicts
> for a year and a half.

Does this mean that he found a way to spend the time training the Brigades without having to first resign his commission?  If so, any indications as to how he pulled that off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Later in Points of Impact he states

> “I have a good idea,” I reply. “I did eighteen months with the Lazarus Brigade as an instructor. Loan from the Fleet, to get their own Combat Controller School off the ground.”

Which suggests he retained his commission but was seconded to the Brigade. How he swung that is less clear - although with the unofficial status of the Brigade, it may have been a request from them to the Fleet to release him.